# Show that $\int d^2\vec{r} \frac{e^{i \vec{q} \vec{r}}}{(1+r^2)^{3/2}}=2 \pi e^{-q}$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I am trying to compute the 2-d Fourier transform:
$$I=\int d^2\vec{r} \frac{e^{i \vec{q} \vec{r}}}{(1+r^2)^{3/2}}$$
In polar coordinates the integral looks like:

$$I=\int^{2\pi}_0d \theta \int^{\infty}_0 dr \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^{3/2}}e^{i q r \cos\theta}$$

I have tried to integrate over the angle first to get a Bessel function, but when I expand it as a series, the integral over $r$ do not converge.

Mathematica gives a simple answer, that is why I am curious on how to derive it.

Comment: Are you sure this is written correctly?

Comment: It's $2\pi$ if $q=0$; more generally, it must be of modulus $\le2\pi$. I'd written an answer that contradicts this, because it neglects certain integrals' divergence, which is why I've deleted it.

Comment: could you please open my question, I have edited it and I believe it is important.

Comment: This still does not quite look like a $2$D Fourier transform. Write the original problem without the polar coordinates if possible.

Comment: thank you, I have reformulated my problem

Comment: Ok, now I get it. It could be easily integrated in cartesian coordinates, by integrating over one variable first, and then by using residue theorem.